# Using action parameters in custom Authorization Attribute in ASP.NET MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, authorization, custom-attributes

I have a controller which should only request authorization when loaded with specific parameters. Like when the parameter ID is 8 for example.

I came up with using a custom validation attribute like this:

```
public class MyAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        if (/* Action's inputparameter ID = 8 */)
        {
        return base.AuthorizeCore(httpContext);
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

My action looks like this (not that it is interesting)

```
[MyAuthorize]
public ActionResult Protected(int id)
{
    /* custom logic for setting the viewmodel from the id parameter */
    return View(viewmodel);
}
```

The problem is as you can see that I don't know how to check for that ID parameter in the authorize attribute.
Can you help me with a solution?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

If the id is passed as request parameter (GET or POST) or as a route data parameter:

```
protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
{
    // first look at routedata then at request parameter:
    var id = (httpContext.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["id"] as string) 
             ??
             (httpContext.Request["id"] as string);
    if (id == "8")
    {
        return base.AuthorizeCore(httpContext);
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: The code is redundant, please see my solution below.

Comment: @Darin, Can you please tell me if the input parameter of the action is a model, how to retrieve that model object instead of named parameters?

Comment: It sounds like you're actually looking for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1335315/access-control-in-asp-net-mvc-depending-on-input-parameters-service-layer

Answer (score 10):

As long as `AuthorizeAttribute` is being inherited, you can get your parameter from `AuthorizationContext`, as follows:

```cs
public class MyAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        string idParam = filterContext.Controller.ValueProvider.GetValue("id").AttemptedValue;
        int id;

        if (int.TryParse(idParam, out id))
        {
            if (id == 8) // apply your business logic here
                return;
        }

        filterContext.Result = new HttpUnauthorizedResult();
    }
}

[MyAuthorize]
public ActionResult Protected(int id)
{
    return View();
}
```

The `ValueProvider` will iterate through all registered providers that by default includes `RouteDataValueProvider`, `QueryStringValueProvider` and `FormValueProvider`, and do all the work for you.

Otherwise I recommend using `ActionFilterAttribute`.

Comment: This does not fully answer my question. I wanted to enable/disable authorization depending on the value of the `id` parameter. Is there a way to affect the Authorization from the `OnAuthorization` handler? Can you elaborate on the `...` part of your answer?

Comment: @SoonDead, I changed my example. As you can see, it is still quite simple, yet fully functional.

Answer (score 2):

You need something like this.

```
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        int? id = GetId(filterContext);

        if (id.HasValue)
        {
          ...
        }
    }

    private static int? GetId(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        int? Id = null;

        if (filterContext.ActionParameters.ContainsKey("Id"))
        {
            Id = (int?)filterContext.ActionParameters["Id"];
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yeah something like that, but I have a HttpContextBase parameter in the AuthorizeCore method, not an ActionExecutingContext. And I don't know how can I write authorization logic in the OnActionExecuting method.

Comment: Here is a great article explaining how to access ActionParameters for authorization purposes: http://www.joe-stevens.com/2010/08/19/asp-net-mvc-authorize-attribute-using-action-parameters-with-the-actionfilterattribute/

Answer (score 1):

```
    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        var rd = httpContext.Request.RequestContext.RouteData;
        string currentAction = rd.GetRequiredString("action");
        string actionparam =Convert.ToString(rd.Values["param"]);

        if (id == actionparam)
        {
            return base.AuthorizeCore(httpContext);
        }
return true;
 }
```

Comment: How does this differ from Darin Dimitrov's answer exactly?